# Как задать BackgroundImage изображением из массива

Tags: reactjs

```
<div
  className="product__section"
  style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(${product.img})' }}
>
```

это пример того что не работает, подскажите как реализовать это правильно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При использовании знака $ нужно ставить обратные ковычки `` вместо ' '.
Вот так должно заработать

```js
<div
  className="product__section"
  style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${product.img})` }}
>
```